# Windows tool to extract the tonal centre of an audio track

Tags: audacity, pitch, measurements

Essentially I want to accurately measure the key that a piece of a cappella music is performed in, to analyze the portions of the piece that are responsible for the tonal centre dropping.

The ideal result would be a graph of pitch (measured in cents relative to starting pitch) vs. time

I can do this manually by listening to a recording and adjusting a tone generator to match what I hear as the tonal centre at a particular point in the piece, then converting the tone generator frequency to cents relative to the starting key, but this is very tedious for a reasonable length piece, and I generally just find the nearest note on a pitch pipe or piano at the end of the piece, but that only tells me that "we dropped roughly 1.5 semitones from start to finish".

I'm interested in any comments using (in particular) Windows tools like Audacity or Sox/FFMPEG, etc, but any discussion welcome.

*** FOOTNOTE ***
Found [this](https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/pitchdetect/) javascript implementation of a web-based pitch detector but I haven't investigated how it will perform with multiple voice parts - i.e. several frequency sources that are each themselves rich in harmonics.

Comment: melodyne is what you need.30d trial.

Comment: @Mark - I was thinking the same, but you'd need the full Studio version to do polyphonic. Probably a bit of a price-shock at €699 https://www.celemony.com/en/melodyne/what-is-melodyne